# Explaining pointer array

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a linking program, consisting of two files. The function createArray() creates an array of some length, which stores random numbers between 0 and 3. It's part of the second file, which gets linked with the first file to create a big program when it's compiled. I have all the declarations from the first file, including the extensions. Anyway, I compile and run the program, but I get a Segmentation Fault error, which I'm assuming it comes down to the line that actually puts the random number into the array.

```
int length;
int* intArray;
int maxRandVal;

void createArray(){
  length = 16;     
  maxRandVal = 3;  
  intArray[length];
  int i = 0;
  for (i; i < length; i++){
    int r = rand() % (maxRandVal+1);
    intArray[i] = r;
  }
}
```

I believe my error is that I'm trying to place an integer into a pointer array - something that I still don't understand how it works. How could I insert my random number into a pointer array?

Comment: In the code there are 2 objects named `intArray`. One is a global pointer, the other is a local array. Make sure you use the correct one. You may like to increase the warning level of your compiler too.

Comment: @pmg: I see no local array?

Comment: @CharlesBailey -- line 2: `int* intArray;` line 8: `intArray[length];`

Comment: @pmg: line 8 is a no-op statement using the pointer declared on line 2, it's not a declaration.

Comment: @pmg In fact `intArray[length];` is just accessing `intArray` on position `length` and discarding the result.

Comment: oops ... my bad! Thanks. I got confused by line 8 just being there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate memory for it first using [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

```
intArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
```

The way you have done does not work. `intArray[length]`

Dont forget to `free` that memory once you are done with it .

Comment: Oh wow rookie mistake... I'm still used to declaring arrays like in Java. Thank you, everything is running correctly now!!

Comment: A better advice would have been to `malloc(sizeof(*intArray)*length)`, which would avoid hardcoding the type of `intArray` in the `malloc` call. Or, even better, if `length` is always 16, use static allocation and avoid the overhead and extra complexity of dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the intArray pointing to? Allocate memory using malloc for length 16.

```
intArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
```

And what are you trying to achive by this:?

```
intArray[length];
```